# How to pass multiple props to an element created by React.createElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> React.createElement(   type,   [props],   [...children] )

as the react documentation said. But somehow it's not working for me with multiple props. I tried to pass an array of key-value objects, pass a container object with key-values, but nothing isn't worked. Let me show how I tried it:

```
//input.js
const Input = ({name, elementProps}) => {
    const { element, props } = elementProps;
    return React.createElement(element, props)
}

export default Input;
//props from
{
    name: "msg",
    element: "textarea",
    props: [
        {placeholder: "Message"},
        {rows: "4"},
        {cols: "50"},
    ]
}
//rendered by method
const { name, ...elementProps } = objectAbove;
return <Input name={name} elementProps={elementProps} />
```

What's the required syntax to pass multiple props?

Comment: `[props]` in the documentation `React.createElement( type, [props], [...children] )` just means that it's optional, not that it is an array. Your props should be an object instead. `{ placeholder: "Message", rows: "4", cols: "50"}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`props` should be a non-array object, not an array. The props array you're creating looks like it could easily be a single object rather than an array of objects. Instead of:

```
props: [
    {placeholder: "Message"},
    {rows: "4"},
    {cols: "50"},
]
```

perhaps

```
props: {
    placeholder: "Message",
    rows: "4",
    cols: "50"
}
```

As [Tholle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle) points out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042449/how-to-pass-multiple-props-to-an-element-created-by-react-createelement/53042541#comment92984389_53042449), the `[]` shown in the syntax in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

```
React.createElement( type, [props], [...children] )
```

...is meant to show that `props` is optional, not that it's an array.